# Lewis Carroll's Pillow Problem via Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

In *Pillow Problems and a Tangled Tale* Lewis Carroll presents the following problem:

> A bag contains a counter, known to be either white or black. A white counter is put in, the bag is shaken, and a counter is drawn out, which proves to be white. What is now the chance of drawing a white counter?

One can easily reason that in the end, the bag must be in one of three states:

- Black remains, new white taken
- New white remains, original white taken
- Original white remains, new white taken

In two of those states, a white counter remains to be drawn. Therefore, the chance is 2/3.

How can one arrive to this answer using Bayes' theorem?

Comment: See my analysis here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993212/probability-inference/2993217#2993217

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715091/is-lewis-carrolls-reasoning-correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let A be the event that the original counter is white.
Let B be the event that you pulled out a white counter.

Bayes' Theorem is:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$

Then $P(B|A)=1, P(A)=\dfrac12, P(B)= P(A)P(B|A) + P(A')P(B|A')= \dfrac34$.

So $P(A|B)=\dfrac12\dfrac43=\dfrac23$.

Comment: I would say $P(A|B)$ is not what we are looking for: we don't want to know the probability of the *original* counter being white, given that we pulled out a white counter, but rather: the probability of the *remaining* counter being white, given that we pulled out a white counter. ... I just did that analysis here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993212/probability-inference/2993217#2993217

Comment: Is this reasoning correct? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4860441/is-this-reasoning-about-bayesian-inference-on-the-lewis-carrolls-pillow-problem